# Rails Minitest: For assert_predicate, is there a not / negate / false version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

In Rails [minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest), there's an [assert_predicate](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/seattlerb/minitest/Minitest/Assertions:assert_predicate) method which asserts that a given method, when called on a given object, returns a truthy value.

Does Minitest have a similar method that passes if the for the given object, the given method returns a *falsy* value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is [`refute_predicate`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/seattlerb/minitest/Minitest/Assertions#refute_predicate-instance_method). Example:

```
# Pass if flash is *not* empty
refute_predicate flash, :empty?
```

Docs on all available minitest assert methods: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/seattlerb/minitest/Minitest/Assertions

Answer (score 0):

the answer above is wrong, it missing the sign ? 
the correct answer is as follow

```
refute_predicate flash, :empty?
```